# NuGet fails to uninstall package recursively if some dependencies are used

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

For example, uninstalling a package with lots of dependencies like `WindowsAzure.Storage`:

1) Uninstall button from the "Manage NuGet packages UI" leaves all the dependencies (mostly unused). *Makes perfect sense, why would I need to uninstall unused dependencies?*

2) OK, so [the docs](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/powershell-reference#uninstall-package) mention `-RemoveDependencies` which is described as:

> Uninstalls the package and its unused dependencies. That is, if any dependency has another package that depends on it, it is skipped.

Description seems pretty clear, quite impressive this is not a default, but whatever, so let's try it in action:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -RemoveDependencies
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'WindowsAzure.Storage.7.1.2' with respect to project '***', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Resolving actions to uninstall package 'WindowsAzure.Storage.7.1.2'
Uninstall-Package : Unable to uninstall 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' because '***, Hyak.Common.1.0.2, Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies.1.0.0' depend on it.
At line:1 char:1
+ Uninstall-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -RemoveDependencies
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UninstallPackageCommand
```

Wat?

No, no other package depends on `WindowsAzure.Storage` (it's pretty much root package)

OK, so maybe something is messed up in the project?

Created new solution, installed `WindowsAzure.Storage` and `Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet` (both depend on `Newtonsoft.Json`), tried to uninstall `WindowsAzure.Storage` - same result.

Is this even supposed to work?

VS 2015 UPD3

**UPD** confirmed to be a bug and likely not getting fixed, apparently the only way to get it to work is to use newer packages model. See accepted answer for the link to created GitHub issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same issue and tested through different version of NuGet Package Manager. So I have submit this issue to GitHub. You could add your comments for this issue.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4026

Before this issue resolved, I'm afraid that we need to uninstall the packages and its dependencies one by one manually.

And you also could use "Uninstall-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -RemoveDependencies -Force" command. Though it will force uninstall the dependencies that depend on by other packages, we could reinstall this dependencies for that packages. It is more quickly than uninstall packages and all its dependencies manually.